# Best way to subtract vector from matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

What is the best way to subtract a vector of length `N` from a matrix of size `(N, K)` in Julia?

Of course, `for` loop or `repmat` should work but they do not seem to be the most efficient.

Can I use `broadcast` somehow?

Comment: Just to clarify, a `for` loop (as long as it's inside a function) *will* be efficient from a computational perspective, but perhaps not from a "keyboarding" perspective. @Tasos's answer is efficient from both perspectives.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
julia> [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] .- [1; 2; 3]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  1  2
 2  3  4
 4  5  6
```

(obviously, subtracting horizontal vectors is also broadcasted)

```
julia> [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] .- [1 2 3]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0
 3  3  3
 6  6  6
```

Also, note that the broadcasted call `.-` in the top example is essentially equivalent to

```
julia> (-).([1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9], [1; 2; 3])
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  1  2
 2  3  4
 4  5  6
```

as of julia 0.6, unifying the `f.(args)` syntax / under-the-hood implementation for broadcasting functions with that for broadcasting operators.
(i.e. `.-` is no longer a separately defined operator, which happens to be a 'broadcasted' version of `-` ).

Comment: In julia parlance, only the first operation in the answer refers to a `Matrix` and a `Vector`, the second refers to two `Matrix`es (check the type of the operands) Normally you'll probably have variables as the operands, so you can't start using semicolons. If you have the `Matrix` and `Vector` as variables: `a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; b = [1,2,3] #standard Vector using commas; a .- b #gives the first example; a .- b' #gives the second example`

Comment: Perhaps you can also mention that you can perform the subtraction in-place like this: `A .= A .- b`?

Comment: @DNF interesting! I wasn't actually aware of that (I would have just done `A[:] = A .- b` instead).

Comment: Actually, `A[:] = A .- b` appears to make an unnecessary allocation, and is slower, so `A .= A .- b` is preferable.

Comment: @DNF yes, exactly. This is good to know. It's not something that appears in the manual or the in-REPL documentation. If find the name to be an interesting choice too; I would have expected `=!` given the `!` convention for functions modifying their argument. I suppose the rationale here is to "perform assignment elementwise (and thus implicitly in-place w.r.t. the lhs input as a whole)", rather than as "an assignment operator that modifies its lhs input in-place"